# His/her vs their after using "each one" (for individual-focused meaning)

Tags: grammatical-number, possessive-pronouns

I have this sentence that intoduce a list of items:

> Encountering a succession of person to observe how each one's way of
>   thinking affects: 
> ● his/her way to look at the world 
> ● his ... 
> ● his
>   ...

I'm tempted to use "their" (as it is recommended in several post), but I do need to keep a clear individual focus, and thus to keep the "each one's". "Their way to look" should not be interpreted in a collective sense ("several people's ways to look" would ruin the meaning)

I want to say that  "*the way of thinking of a single person* influences *the way to look at the world* of that **particular person**". (meaning 1)

I don't want to say: "*the way of thinking of a single person encoutered* influences* the way to look at the world* of **all** the person encountered". (meaning 2)

Using *their* seems to imply meaning 1 as well as the 2, while using *his/her* will clearly imply meaning 1 without risking any confusion with meaning 2.

Knowing that context, should I use "each one" with a list of items started with "their" or should I write "his/her way to look a the world" (and then keep only the *his* for the other items)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all of your bullet points starts with a possessive pronoun, just move that up to the top line.

That means that you can use a longer phrase, because it's only used once.

> Encountering a succession of people to observe how each one's way of thinking affects that individual's
>   ● way of looking at the world
>   ● ...
>   ● ...

[I've made a couple of other small adjustments in the wording too.]

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting, but it sound like a bit like if it was *each of the person of the encountered group* that were looking at single *individual*.

Comment: Er, no it doesn't. The *that* in "that individual" references the *one* in "each one". You could add say "that individual's own" if you are particularly concerned about it.

Comment: I wonder if I could use "person" instead of "individual", since "person" has a warmer connotation than "individual" in several languages (french, Italian). What do you think?